# Multiple Stripe accounts in one form

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

With Stripe, can I have two charges from two different stripe accounts on one form? ie) Have the setup fee be sent Company A and the product fee sent to Company B...

I am creating a subscription based website however, I need to charge consumers a fee for their transaction as well as send the payment directly to the company. Example: The consumer will be charge a transaction fee of $5, which will go to my company. Furthermore, the price of the product will go to the company that posts the product. Therefore, I get the transaction fee and the company gets the money for their product.

Is there a way to do this with Stripe?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd need to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) to accept payments on behalf of other accounts, and optionally take a cut.

In your case, your account would be the platform's account and the company that ships the product would be a connected account.

You could then accept charges on behalf of this company, and specify your own application fee: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees